# Puzzlemaker in Portal 2

Tags: portal-2

I want to connect 2 button to one single dropper. I know how to connect but split into 2 connectors isolated... I don't know how to. I'll make a example:

As normally, if i connect 2 objects to the dropper, the dropper will only launch a cube AFTER we press to 2 buttons in same time. BUT i want to do in a different way, the 2 button work isolated. As i said before, it will only work after i press the 2 in same time.

( "." = deactivated connector

"," = activated connector

"O" = button

"U" = dropper

"H" = cube)

O . . . . . . U . . . . . . O

Now, i will press one of buttons.

o , , , , , , U . . . . . . O

See? If i press one of them, the dropper doens't work! But i want a solution, i want press a button and it work! As below:

|              U 
|             ||| 
|o , , , , , , H . . . . . . O

And that's i want. Some solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want an **OR logic gate**.

You will need to add 2 lasers and 1 receiver to your puzzle. Instead of connecting buttons to dropper, connect them to lasers. Then connect receiver to dropper, just like this:

```
L     R     L
◦     ◦     ◦
◦     U     ◦  deactivated state
◦           ◦
O           O

L—————R ◦ ◦ L
•     •     ◦
•     U     ◦  activated by left button
•    |||    ◦
O     H     O

L ◦ ◦ R—————L
◦     •     •
◦     U     •  activated by right button
◦    |||    •
O     H     O
```

where:

- "◦" - deactivated connector
- "•" - activated connector
- "—" - laser beam
- O - button
- U - dropper
- H - cube
- L - laser
- R - receiver